# Llenar DropDown al seleccionar otro dropdown android

Tags: android, android-studio, dropdownlist

Tengo el siguiente codigo donde obtengo data de mi SQLitedatabase y quiero que este rellene otro DropDown mediante unos datos en `SQLitedatabase`.

Actualmente me rellena con el primer  List.Pero quiero mediante este llene otro.

Creacion de formulario

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView,autoCompleteTextVieww;
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapterItem;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_clasificacion2);

        SQLiteClass db = new SQLiteClass(AddClasificacion.this);
        List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();

        adapterItem = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_angulos,lables);
        autoCompleteTextViewww.setAdapter(adapterItem);
        autoCompleteTextViewww.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                itemmm = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();
                /*Aqui selecciono y para ir a buscar data*/
//              List<String> labless = db.getByLabels(itemmm);
            }
        });

 }
```

DB Class

```
public List<String> getRodalPredio(String nombre){
        List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM data WHERE nombre= '"+nombre+"'";

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                labels.add(cursor.getString(2));
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return labels;
    }
```